# How to create simple XML in OmniXML

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, omnixml

i want to create this structure xml

```
<root ver="" file=""> 
  <row> 
    <id></id> 
    <name></name> 
    <surname></surname> 
    <time></time> 
    <old></old> 
    <subject></subject> 
  </row> 
</root>
```

when i do the main structure i get the data from online database and i want to add it in my xml file

1. how can i create the main structure
2. how can i add a new Row in every update the database made
3. how can i sort the xml, base of the name node

Please help

Thank you

Comment: you have asked 3 questions, you need to ask a question at a time and probably post a link to the previous question(s) since they are tied together

Comment: Which part of the task are you having trouble with?

Comment: Sorry Dorin i thougth it is simple questions (exept the sort thing) and i thing to put all together so if anyone else want something like this to have a complete mini tutorial how to solve this...

Comment: Rod the most difficult must be the sort thing...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use create inherited classes which define your xml

```
interface

uses
  OmniXML, OmniXMLProperties;

type
  TRow = class(TGpXMLData)
  public
    constructor Create(Node: IXMLNode); override;

    property Id: integer index 0 read GetXMLPropInt write SetXMLPropInt;
    property Name: WideString index 1 read GetXMLPropWide write SetXMLPropWide;
    property Surname: WideString index 2 read GetXMLPropWide write SetXMLPropWide;
    property Time: WideString index 3 read GetXMLPropWide write SetXMLPropWide;
    property Old: WideString index 4 read GetXMLPropWide write SetXMLPropWide;
    property Subject: WideString index 5 read GetXMLPropWide write SetXMLPropWide;
  end;

  TRows = class(TGpXMLList)
  protected
    function GetRow(Value: integer): TRow;
  public
    constructor Create(ParentNode: IXMLNode); reintroduce;

    function Add: TRow; reintroduce;

    property Rows[Value: integer]: TRow read GetRow; default;
  end;

  TRootsXml = class(TGpXmlDocList)
  private
    fRows: TRows;
  public
    constructor Create; reintroduce;
    destructor Destroy; override;

    property Ver: WideString index 0 read GetXMLAttrPropWide write SetXMLAttrPropWide;
    property RootFile: WideString index 1 read GetXMLAttrPropWide write SetXMLAttrPropWide;

    property Rows: TRows read fRows;
  end;

implementation

constructor TRow.Create(Node: IXMLNode);
begin
  inherited;

  InitChildNodes(['id', 'name', 'surname', 'time', 'old', 'subjects'], 
    ['', '', '', '', '', '']);
end;

constructor TRows.Create(parentNode: IXMLNode);
begin
  inherited Create(parentNode, '', 'row', TRow);
end;

function TRows.Add: TRow;
begin
  result := TRow(inherited Add);
end;

function TRows.GetRow(Value: Integer): TRow;
begin
  Result := TRow(inherited Items[Value]);
end;

constructor TRootsXml.Create;
var
  xmlPI: IXMLProcessingInstruction;
begin
  inherited Create('Root', '', '', nil);

  xmlPI := XMLDoc.CreateProcessingInstruction('xml', 'version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"');
  XMLDoc.InsertBefore(xmlPI, node);

  InitChildNodes(['ver', 'file'], ['', '']);

  fRows := TRows.Create(node);
end; 

destructor TRootsXml.Destroy;
begin
  fRows.free;

  inherited;
end;
```

After that write a procedure to export the data e.g.

```
procedure TExport.Exportrows;
var
  rootsXml: TRootsXml;
  row: TRow;
  i: integer;
begin
  rootsXml := TRootsXml.Create;
  try
    rootsXml.Ver := 'version 27';
    rootsXml.RootFile := 'fred.exe';

    for i := 1 to 10 do
    begin
      row := rootsXml.Rows.Add;

      row.Id := i;
      row.Name := 'fred';  
      row.Surname := 'Flintstone';
      row.Time := 'late';
      row.Old := 'very';
      row.Subject := 'Delphi';
    end;

    rootsXml.SaveToFile('c:\test\test.xml', ofIndent);
  finally
    rootsXml.free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Gavin when i try to add in "rootsXml.ver" something i get the internal error e5912... But the program builds succesfully... something with the property thing is but i can't find it can you help me...

Answer (score 4):

Using [GpFluentXML](http://www.thedelphigeek.com/2009/10/gpfluentxml-3.html):

```
var
  root : IXMLNode;
  rowID: integer;
  xml  : IGpFluentXmlBuilder;
begin
  xml := CreateFluentXml
    .AddChild('root')
      ['ver', '']
      ['file', '']
    .Anchor(root);
  for rowID := 1 to 10 do begin
    xml
      .Jump(root)
      .AddChild('row')
        .AddChild('id', rowID)
        .AddSibling('name', '')
        .AddSibling('surname', '')
        .AddSibling('time', '')
        .AddSibling('old', '')
        .AddSibling('subject', '');
  end;
  XMLSaveToFile(xml.Xml, 'filename', ofIndent);
end;
```

Using OmniXMLUtils (part of the OmniXML distribution):

```
var
  row  : IXMLNode;
  rowID: integer;
  xml  : IXMLDocument;
begin
  xml := ConstructXMLDocument('root');
  SetNodeAttr(xml.DocumentElement, 'ver', '');
  SetNodeAttr(xml.DocumentElement, 'file', '');
  for rowID := 1 to 10 do begin
    row := AppendNode(xml, 'row');
    SetNodeTextInt(row, 'id', rowID);
    SetNodeText(row, 'name', '');
    SetNodeText(row, 'surname', '');
    SetNodeText(row, 'time', '');
    SetNodeText(row, 'old', '');
    SetNodeText(row, 'subject', '');
  end;
  XMLSaveToFile(xml, 'filename', ofIndent);
end;
```

As for the sorting, you don't sort the XML; you sort the data before adding it to the document.

Answer (score 3):

With the standard component, TXMLDocument: (if you don't find other solution, maybe you can copy the xml generated by TXMLDocument to your OmniXML :/)

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, xmldom, XMLIntf, StdCtrls, msxmldom, XMLDoc;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    xmldoc1: TXMLDocument;
    btn1: TButton;
    procedure btn1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.btn1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  xmldoc1.XML.Text := '<root ver="" file=""></root>'; //<row><id></id><name></name><surname></surname><time></time><old></old><subject></subject></row>';
  xmldoc1.Active   := True;

  for I := 0 to 9 do
  begin
    with xmldoc1.ChildNodes['root'].AddChild('row') do
    begin
      AddChild('name').Text    := 'NAME' + IntToStr(I);
      AddChild('surname').Text := 'SURNAME';
      AddChild('time').Text    := TimeToStr(Now);
      AddChild('old').Text     := IntToStr(20);
      AddChild('subject').Text := 'SUBJECT';
    end;
  end;

  ShowMessage(xmldoc1.XML.Text);
end;

end.
```

With OmniXML, something like this should work:

```
uses OmniXML;

var
  aChild: IXMLElement;
  aRow  : IXMLElement;
  rowID : Integer;
  XMLDoc: IXMLDocument;
begin
  XMLDoc := CreateXMLDoc;
  XMLDoc.DocumentElement := XMLDoc.CreateElement('root');
  XMLDoc.DocumentElement.SetAttribute('ver', 'value');
  XMLDoc.DocumentElement.SetAttribute('file', 'value');
  for rowID := 1 to 10 do begin
    aRow   := XMLDoc.CreateElement('row');
    XMLDoc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(aRow);
    aChild := XMLDoc.CreateElement('id');
    aChild.Text := IntToStr(rowID);
    aRow.AppendChild(aChild);
    aChild := XMLDoc.CreateElement('name');
    aChild.Text := 'NAME';
    aRow.AppendChild(aChild);
    aChild := XMLDoc.CreateElement('surname');
    aChild.Text := 'SURNAME';
    aRow.AppendChild(aChild);
    //...
  end;

  XMLDoc.Save('filename', ofIndent);
end;
```

Comment: Azrael asked "how to add a new Row every ..." so I expanded your OmniXML example with an iteration that adds more than one row. Maybe you can do the same for the TXMLDocument example?